# Redirect all output with prompt to a file

Tags: bash, io-redirection, prompt

What is the shortest way to redirect: `$PROMPT`, last executed command, `stdout` and `stderr` into single file?

Of course, we might use `&>` to redirect `stdout` and `stderr` into single file and then add `$PROMPT` and `$!!` and at the beginning and at the end of file, respectively.

I would like to see my log file as:

```
$PROMPT: $LAST_EXECUTED_COMMAND
$STOUD_STDERR
$PROMPT
```

Answer (score 5):

What you wan tot achieve is a typescript of a terminal session. For this you could use `script`.

Start recording with:

```
$ script logfile
Script started, file is logfile
$
```

Now type your commands and, when finished, exit with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>. You can now view that file with:

```
less -r logfile
```

In that file is the input, output, error messages, the shell prompt and so on.